# Adding some string before specific characters in Java

Tags: java, string, loops, character

I want to add "OB" before every vowel.
Sample input: "THIS IS A TEST"
Sample output: "THOBIS OBIS OBA TOBEST"
I have no idea why my code doesn't work:

```
public static String obify(String test) {
    int x = 0;
    while (x != -1) {
        if (test.charAt(x) == 'A' || test.charAt(x) == 'E' || test.charAt(x) == 'I' || test.charAt(x) == 'O' || test.charAt(x) == 'U') {
            test = test.replace(test.substring(x, x+1), "ob" + test.substring(x, x+1));
            x += 3;
        } else {
            x++;
        }
        if (x >= test.length() - 1) {
            x = -1;
        }
    }
    return test;
}
```

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/5221149)

Comment: You could also just use `input.replaceAll("A", "OBA").replaceAll("E", "OBE")` and so on, or directly use regex `input.replaceAll("([AEIOU])", "OB$1")`. Also, what is the output of your current solution?

Comment: In what way is it not working? Does it fail with an error? If so, show us the stacktrace. Is the output incorrect? If so, show us what you get.

Comment: `replace` method replace all currencies of its first parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Perfect scenario for a simple regex

```
String foo = "hEllo what's up?";
String rep = foo.replaceAll("(?i)([aeiou])", "OB$1");
System.out.println(rep);
```

Comment: While this solves the task OP tries to solve, it does not explain why his approach is not working as intended.

Comment: also, wont this delete the vowel the OP intended on keeping?

Comment: @Jason the $1 is the matched vowel

Comment: Perfect, this was what I was going to answer as well.

Comment: thanks man. although i don't understand about it since i'm still new to this. but i'll get back to it later

Comment: You’ll get additional information from reading the comments @BlahBlah  also read about regex, it’s pretty helpful. Please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace

```
test = test.replace(test.substring(x, x+1), "ob" + test.substring(x, x+1));
```

with

```
test = test.substring(0, x) +
        "ob" +
        test.substring(x, x + 1) +
        test.substring(x + 1);
```

Your problem is that `replace` act on all occurrences of its first parameter.

When you have "THobIS **I**S A TEST" and try to replace marked letter you replace both "I" letter. After it you index points to completely wrong position before second "I". Sooner or later you get to it again and situation repeats.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in `replace` call. 
Documentaion tells that it replaces each substring with new one. 
So your string grows infinitely:
after first replace it is: "THobIS obIS A TEST"
after next one is: "THobobIS obobIS A TEST"
then "THobobobIS obobobIS A TEST"
and so on...

If you change your line

`test = test.replace(test.substring(x, x+1), "ob" + test.substring(x, x+1));`

to

`test = test.substring(0, x) + "ob" + test.substring(x);`

it will do the work.

Also you can change while condition to `x < test.length()` and get rid of second if.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier this way: For the word "GTREIS":
I basically take what was before and after the vowel(including the vowel) and attaching "OB"to the first part, attaching the remaining and finally replacing the original string with the modified one.

```
public static String  obify(String s)
{ 
    String inloc ="OB",aux="";
    String start="";
    int n=s.length();
    int i=0;

    while (i<n)
    {
        if(s.charAt(i)=='A'|| s.charAt(i)=='E' || s.charAt(i)=='I' ||     s.charAt(i)=='O'||s.charAt(i)=='U' ){
            inloc ="OB";
            start="";
            aux=s.substring(i);//EIS
            System.out.println(aux);
            start=s.substring(0,i);//GTR
            System.out.println(start);
            start=start+inloc;//GTROB
            System.out.println(start);
            start=start+aux;
            s=start;
            i+=3;// here you have to jump over OBE for example and search the next vowel 
            n+=2;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for answering. Please properly format and indent your code